# Qt in Visual Studio 2012, "error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory"

Tags: qt, opengl, visual-studio-2012

I errors and a warning when I try to compile some openGL projects for Qt.
Many of them are:

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory    d:\documents\code\qt5pack\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.1\qtbase\src\corelib\global\qglobal.h    46  1   01-createcontext
```

Using Qt and OpenGL with Visual Studio or Creator is giving me a headache. I noticed that my $VCInstallDir is to VC10.. I don't know if that is anything important.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem and struggled with it for a few days.  My situation was this:
Had VSE 2013 installed, Qt 5.3.1 (64 bit), and OpenCV 2.4.9 (64 bit).  Was working fine, building projects in QtCreator + OpenCV using the VS 2013 compiler.  Then I was trying to incorporate CUDA and found that the CUDA compiler was not compatible with VS 2013 so had to downgrade to 2012.  That's when the problem started.  Tried repairing, uninstalling, reinstalling...nothing seemed to work.  I kept reading in posts that it probably had something to do with the Microsoft Platform SDK not being installed or installed correctly.  So I went to this site to download a fresh copy and noticed that down the page there was a section that described how to uninstall it, including some manual steps.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx

So, here's what I did to get everything working.  Maybe all these steps were not required, but this is what I did.

1) uninstall VSE 2012 (I had already gotten rid of VSE 2013), and deleted the folders C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0 and C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 which both had some residual stuff in them after the uninstall.  NOTE: Remember that VS 2012 is really Visual Studio 11.0 and VS 2010 is Visual Studio 10.0.

2) uninstall all Microsoft .NET Framework SDKs (there were a few on my machine 4.5 and 4.51)

3) uninstall all Microsoft .NET Framework Multi-Targeting Packs, which apparently is part of the SDK.  Again, there were several on my machine...I guess from different versions.

4) reinstall VSE 2012

5) reinstall the Microsoft SDK.  For me this was the latest version 8.1 which works for Windows 7, 8, and 8.1.

6) made sure all my kits were right in QtCreator, which they were, and it all worked again.

Hope this helps someone.

Now I can get back to re-compiling OpenCV with all the NVidia/GPU options.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

VS2012 should actually point to VC11...
Have you checked your projects properties? Have you installed the Windows SDK?

Comment: I thought so.. That's a bit weird! Under "D:Programmer(x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows" I have 4 folders: v7.0A, v7.1A, v8.0, v8.0A.

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to building, making and configuring projects and compiling from source. I don't know what exactly was wrong, but I think it might have had to do with the VS2010 express installation I did earlier this month. I "repaired" VS2012 using the uninstaller and now it seems to work.